# C/C++: "mod 2" not resulting in the same instructions as "and 1" (gcc -O3)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, compiler-optimization

When compiling these two snippets with gcc and maximum optimization (GCC 11.1.0, `gcc -std=c11 -O3`), I expected to obtain the exact **same executable**, since the `%2` and `&1` operations are **equivalent**. After disassembling with `objdump`, though, the two object files differed. The output is shown below.

#### And

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   return argc & 1;
}
```

```
0000000000001020 <main>:
    1020:       89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
    1022:       83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
    1025:       c3                      ret    
    1026:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    cs nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

#### Modulus

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   return argc % 2;
}
```

```
0000000000001020 <main>:
    1020:       89 fa                   mov    %edi,%edx
    1022:       c1 ea 1f                shr    $0x1f,%edx
    1025:       8d 04 17                lea    (%rdi,%rdx,1),%eax
    1028:       83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
    102b:       29 d0                   sub    %edx,%eax
    102d:       c3                      ret    
    102e:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

I understand the instructions in the first program, but I don't quite get the purpose of some lines of the second.

- `shr $0x1f,%edx` should mean "shift right by 31 bits of `%edx`"
- `lea (%rdi,%rdx,1),%eax` should mean "save in `%eax` the value saved at the address `%rdi + %rdx * 1`"

Why are the two programs different? Why isn't the compiler optimizing `%2` to `&1`, which is supposedly faster and uses less instructions?

Comment: You used signed integer where `% 2` is **not equivalent** to `& 1` If you cast it to `unsigned` the compiler will (likely) generate the same code. It does on godbolt.

Comment: `%2` and `&1` are not equivalent for negative numbers

Comment: `x % 2` is not the same as `x & 1`, since `x%2` is -1 if x is negative and odd. The compiler would have to know that `argc` can't be negative.

Comment: Your interpretation of `lea` seems to be wrong. It means "load effective address" and loads the sum of `%rdi` and `%rdx` in `%eax`.

Comment: The purpose of the shr instruction is to isolate the sign bit, in order to obtain different behavior when the value is negative.

Comment: Right, thank you everyone. Why the downvote though? I think the question shows research effort, I just didn't think that the modulus operation would do something different on negative numbers, sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val % 2` may have negative value if `val` is negative. `val & 1` will only have a positive value (or zero). So those operations are not identical - thus different compiled code.

Comment: Ok, right, I tried using `unsigned int` and it actually generates the sane exact code. Thank you!